# Flash Dev tools for Mac?

Tags: flash, macos

What tools do you use to write ActionScript on the Mac?
Preferably opensource or free...

Comment: try to ask this on http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Nobody has enough rep yet to move this!

Comment: They will get moderators here in a bit, but by then this will probably be pretty dead.

Comment: if you're a student you get FlexBuilder for free, otherwise, TextMate+as3 bundle+flex sdk like PiPeep said is the cheapest/easiest way to go. as3 dev support is a lot better on PC IMHO ( I haven't seen anything this good on a Mac that is also free http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?t=23 )

Answer (score 0):

Should be on SO, but...

- Flex Builder and FDT are available for mac, although expensive
- TextMate + AS3 Bundle + Free Flex SDK, is inexpensive, and works very well
- You can hack on AS3 support to XCode and use the free Flex SDK to compile

Answer (score 0):

I use TextMate + Flash CS4 for Flash.  Neither of which are free.